# Having trouble with FireFox & Jquery -  overflow hidden/auto properties

Tags: jquery, html, css, firefox, css-float

As the title mentions i'm having a problem getting Firefox to animate a container element with the class name .mover - left : 0% and back to left : 100%.

I've put together an example here..
http://jsbin.com/ucefig/28

Scroll down to the yellow page, 'who we are', then select the black box, this should animate the .mover element to the left. Click it again on the revealed 'our people' page, and it should return to its original position.

My code works on IE9, chrome and safari, but fails on Firefox ??

the picture illustrates my dilemma in the example above, the grey box is the .mover element thats animated on, the squares are the pages. in FF .mover topscrolls to 0 then animates left into a void.

[image]

Thanks
cam

Comment: If you have found the answer to your own question, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ANSWER - Setting the 'html' overflow properties to 'hidden'/'auto' was the culprit.

Working example in FF;
http://jsbin.com/opevoz/2/